# Too much data in a cell to display in a Userform Listbox

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a listbox in a userform in Excel 2007.

Some cells in my worksheet contain more than 10 rows (data with ALT ENTER).

I'm trying to clean and display the data. I don't want to change the column width to 1000, but I'd like to use a mouseover box to show all the cell data.

Is there another idea that would work?

Comment: Are you trying to show the data in the sheet or in the form? I don't understand what your asking. If your form/list box are not important and you just want to be able to see all the lines in the sheet by some means then say that. Otherwise can you elaborate a bit.

Comment: My sheet view is not important, my form is important. I want it do be displayed clean in my listbox on my Form. Preferably with a mouse over and a little toolbox. But i can't find anyone who ever did or tried this.

Comment: The Cells with multiple lines, does each line in the cell represent one item in the list? or does the whole cell value get put into a single list item. Could you maybe provide some screenshots? (update your question with links)

Answer (score 1):

With mouse over would be possible to do it but it is complicated I think. Here I have another simpler idea: on double click in list box a multi line text box with selected list item(s) data will be shown. This text box has the same position and size as the list box. On the user form click text box hides. Here is some sample code, to test it you need form with list box named "ListBox1":

```
Option Explicit

Public ListItemInfo As Control

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set ListItemInfo = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "ListItemInfo", False)
    With Me.ListItemInfo
        .Top = Me.ListBox1.Top
        .Left = Me.ListBox1.Left
        .Width = Me.ListBox1.Width
        .Height = Me.ListBox1.Height
        .MultiLine = True
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
    Me.ListItemInfo.text = GetSelectedItemsText
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    SwitchListItemInfo
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()
    SwitchListItemInfo
End Sub

Private Function GetSelectedItemsText() As String
    Dim text As String
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If Me.ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
            text = text & Me.ListBox1.List(i) & vbNewLine
        End If
    Next i
    GetSelectedItemsText = text
End Function

Private Sub SwitchListItemInfo()
    If Me.ListItemInfo.text = "" Then Exit Sub
    Me.ListItemInfo.Visible = Not Me.ListItemInfo.Visible
    Me.ListBox1.Visible = Not Me.ListBox1.Visible
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You're welcome. If you like the answer please upvote it. I will be happy to get some points :-).