# Listbox Userform Workaround for Wrap Text by Displaying Popup of Selection

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

A user asked a question about using a mouseover tool to display cut off data in a Listbox column. "Dee" posted the following solution (see, https://stackoverflow.com/a/15301355/4362915):

```
Option Explicit

Public ListItemInfo As Control

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set ListItemInfo = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "ListItemInfo", False)
    With Me.ListItemInfo
        .Top = Me.ListBox1.Top
        .Left = Me.ListBox1.Left
        .Width = Me.ListBox1.Width
        .Height = Me.ListBox1.Height
        .MultiLine = True
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
    Me.ListItemInfo.text = GetSelectedItemsText
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    SwitchListItemInfo
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()
    SwitchListItemInfo
End Sub

Private Function GetSelectedItemsText() As String
    Dim text As String
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If Me.ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
            text = text & Me.ListBox1.List(i) & vbNewLine
        End If
    Next i
    GetSelectedItemsText = text
End Function

Private Sub SwitchListItemInfo()
    If Me.ListItemInfo.text = "" Then Exit Sub
    Me.ListItemInfo.Visible = Not Me.ListItemInfo.Visible
    Me.ListBox1.Visible = Not Me.ListBox1.Visible
End Sub
```

In brief, Dee's code populates ListBox1 from a select range dictated in the RowSource value of the listbox; when you double click one of the items, a new TextBox pops up listing the contents of the item double clicked.  All of this is done, of course, simply because ListBox cannot wrap text and cuts off text when the value is too long.

I have a listbox populated with 5 columns of data pulled from an Access db.  I frequently have the problem where certain columns of data are cut off -- thus, Dee's solution of a pop-up text box is very appealing.  However, I am struggling revising Dee's code so that the listbox is populated from my access db and not a pre-specified range in the RowSource field of the ListBox properties.  I'm struggling to do this, but I'm guessing the solution is pretty obviously to an expert, so any help would be greatly, greatly appreciated.  The code of my current listbox is as follows:

```
Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim NoOfRecords As Long
  'Open the .accdb form database to retrieve data
  s = ActiveCell.Value
  Set db = OpenDatabase("\\BTT\test.accdb")
  'Define the first recordset
  Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Entities WHERE [Entity Name] Like '" & s & "' & '*' ")
  'Determine the number of records in the recordset
  On Error GoTo ErrHandler
  With rs
    .MoveLast
    NoOfRecords = .RecordCount
    .MoveFirst
  End With
  'Set the number of ListBox columns = number of fields in the recordset
  ListBox1.ColumnCount = 5
  'Load the listbox with the retrieved records
  ListBox1.Column = rs.GetRows(NoOfRecords)
    'Cleanup
  rs.Close
  db.Close
  Call Easy
  Set rs = Nothing
  Set db = Nothing
lbl_Exit:
  Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
  MsgBox "No historical results for this entity"
  Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Set Me.Listbox1.Recordset = rs
```

Untested but some further info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836245%28v=office.15%29.aspx)